# Pagination {auto_path} outputting 3 x duplicate URL

Tags: url, config, transcribe, pagination

I have an odd problem with EE 2.5.3 outputting multiple urls preceding the correct pagination segment when using this code:

```
{paginate}
{if next_page}
<a href="{auto_path}"Next</a>
{/if}
{/paginate}
```

It outputs the following: `http://www.domain.co.uk/http://www.domain.co.uk/http://www.domain.co.uk/news/P6`

Interesting, if manually navigate to `http://www.domain.co.uk/P6`   (or P0) then it then outputs the correct link - it is only when there is no pagination segment in the url that it does not work.

If I change the setting "URL to the root directory of your site" in the general config from `http://www.domain.co.uk/` to just `/` then it works and outputs the correct link.  However, this causes other problems with sitemaps and so on, so it's not an ideal solution.

The name of the site's index page is left blank as I am using rewriting to remove the index.php from the urls.

There is nothing that I can see in the config files that would be adding an additional two `http://www.domain.co.uk`s to the output.

If it might be relevant, the site is using EEHarbour's Transcribe plugin (a pre-release beta of 1.6) and Structure 3.3.13 and Freebie 0.2.2

Hope someone can help!
Many thanks, Michael

Answer (score 1):

Right, I've solved this by adding `paginate_base="news"` into the channel:entries tag and it works correctly now.

I have no idea why it was broken in the first place though!